Receiving "Property 'Flatlist' Doesn't Exist", But I'm Pretty Sure I Imported It
The title pretty much says it all (lol). My code is as follows:
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button} from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default function ExpoImagePicker() {

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);


  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsMultipleSelection:true,
      aspect: [1,1],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets.uri);    
    }
}
  return ( 
    <Flatlist
        contentContainerStyle = {{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}
        horizontal
        data={setImage} 
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
         <Image source = {{uri: item}} style = {{width: 280, height: 280}}></Image>
       )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        ListFooterComponent={() => <Button title = "Pick From Media Library" onPress=           {pickImage} style={{display:'flex', flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>  </Button>}
  />
  );
}

I've tried searching the error message via Google and I put the import { Flatlist } line separately as well

"L" in FlatList should be in capital letter. But your component used Flatlist.

It is because of the typo in Flatlist, Try removing it and import it once again.
let it autocomplete than you writing it.
